# Can someone explain to me why the app function of ArrowApply makes them as powerful as monads?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, arrows

So I'll break my question into 4 parts, but first some background:

I feel relatively comfortable with Monads, but not very comfortable with Arrows. I suppose the main problem I have with them is, I don't see what they are useful for. Whether formally correct or not, I understand Monads to be a tool that allows us to introduce side effects from computation. As they generalize program fragments from pure values to values boxed with other actions. From my shotgun "read all the papers" approach to learning about arrows, I've come across two conflicting viewpoints:

A. Arrows are more powerful than Monads/ are generalizations of Monads.
The haskell wiki starts off with "They can do everything monads can do, and more. They are roughly comparable to monads with a static component."

B. Arrows are a subset of Monads
With ArrowApply we can define a monad

1. Is there any truth to viewpoint A?
2. What kind of functionality do arrows not have, I've read that the difference has to do with composition, so what does the >>> operator allow us to do that >>= doesn't?
3. What does app exactly do? it's type doesn't even have an (->)
4. Why would we ever want to use applicative arrows over monads?

Comment: Have you read [Idioms are oblivious, arrows are meticulous, monads are promiscuous](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/arrows-and-idioms/arrows-and-idioms.pdf)?

Comment: Also check out: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows

Comment: yeah, I've read the wikibook page in it's entirety. I started learning Haskell 3 months ago, and just stumbled onto arrows. I find most sources on arrows unaccessable i.e. Hughes paper

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi Yes, arrows are are very complex conceptually. If you've been learning Haskell for just a few months, I think arrows are hard to understand. Make sure you understand Monads and Applicative functors - they're a bit easier to get, and more widely used.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Multiply-interpretable statements alert:

> "A is more powerful than B" ... "C is a generalisation of D" ... "E can do everything F can do, and more" ... "G is a subset of H" ...

First we need to get a grip on what we mean by powerful etc. Suppose we had a class `GripHandle` for things which had a grip handle, and another class `Screwdriver` for screwdrivers. Which is more powerful?

- Well clearly, if you just have a griphandle, that's not as useful as if you're a screwdriver; a griphandle on its own isn't much use, so obviously since you can do more with a screwdriver than a griphandle, so screwdrivers are more powerful.
- Well clearly, more things have a grip handle than just screwdrivers - drills, knives and forks, all sort of things have griphandles, so griphandles are more powerful and flexible.
- Well clearly, if you have a screwdriver, you can not only hold it, you can turn it, and having the ability to turn rather than just hold makes screwdrivers much more powerful and flexible than griphandles.

OK, that's a silly argument, but it raises a good point about how the phrase "You can do more with a _____" is rather ambiguous.

If you stick to the interface alone, **a** screwdriver is more useful than **a** handle, but **all** things with griphandles are together more useful than **all** screwdrivers if you use more functions than just the interface.

### How hierarchy works

`A` is more general than `B`
= `A`'s interface-only capabilities are a subset of `B`'s = you can do more with a `B` instance (alone)
= The class of all `B`s is a subset of the class of all `A`s = there are more `A`s than `B`s = you can do more with the `A` class

more general
= more possible instances
= able to be more widely used
= can do extra things behind the scenes
= fewer capabilities are specified in the interface
= can do fewer things *via* the interface

### What's the hierarchy between arrows and monads?

- `Arrow` is more general than `Monad`.
- `ArrowApply` is exactly as general as `Monad`.

These two statements are proved in full detail in the paper Petr Pudlák linked to in his comment: [Idioms are oblivious, arrows are meticulous, monads are promiscuous](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/arrows-and-idioms/arrows-and-idioms.pdf).

### The assertions in A and B

- **"Arrows can do everything monads can do, and more."**
  This is marketing. It's true, but you have to jump around a bit semantically to make it true. An `ArrowApply` instance on its own allows you to do everything a `Monad` instance on its own does. You can't do more with an `ArrowApply` than with a `Monad`. You *can* do more with things that are `Arrows`. The claim "everything monads can do" probably refers to `ArrowApply` while the claim "and more" probably refers to `Arrow`! The Monad marketing board could say "With Monads, you can do everything Arrows can do, and more" because of the increased expressiveness of the interface. These statements are ambiguous and have little formal meaning because of that.
- **"They are roughly comparable to monads with a static component."**
  Strictly speaking, no, that's just something you can do with `Arrow` that you can't do directly with a `Monad`, not a mathematical fact about the Arrow interface. It's a way of helping you get to grips with what we might do with an Arrow, in a similar way to the analogy of a Monad being a box with a value in. Not all monads are readily interpretable as a box with a value in, but it might help you a bit in the early stages.
- **"Arrows are a subset of Monads"**
  This is perhaps misleading. It *is* true that the interface-only capabilities of Arrows are a subset of the interface-only capabilities of Monads, but it's fairer to say that the class of all Monads is a subset of the class of all Arrows, because `Arrow` is more general.
- **"With ArrowApply we can define a monad"**
  Yes. See later, and with a Monad, we can define an ArrowApply.

## Your four questions

1. **Is there any truth to viewpoint A?**
     Some. See above. There's some truth in B too. Both are misleading in some way or other.
2. **What kind of functionality do arrows not have, I've read that the difference has to do with composition, so what does the >>> operator allow us to do that >>= doesn't?**
    In fact `>>=` allows you do to more than `>>>` (more interface-supplied capability). It allows you to context-switch. This is because `Monad m => a -> m b` is a function, so you can execute arbitrary pure code on the input `a` before deciding which monadic thing to run, whereas `Arrow m => m a b` isn't a function, and you've decided which arrow thing is going to run before you examined the input `a`.

   ```
   monadSwitch :: Monad m => m a -> m a -> (Bool -> m a)
   monadSwitch computation1 computation2 test 
         = if test then computation1 else computation2
   ```

   It's not possible to simulate this using `Arrow` without using `app` from `ArrowApply`
3. **What does app exactly do? it's type doesn't even have an (->)**
    It lets you use the output of an arrow as an arrow. Let's look at the type.

   ```
   app :: ArrowApply m => m (m b c, b) c
   ```

   I prefer to use `m` to `a` because `m` feels more like a computation and `a` feels like a value. Some people like to use a type operator (infix type constructor), so you get

   ```
   app :: ArrowApply (~>) => (b ~> c, b) ~> c
   ```

   We think of `b ~> c` as an arrow, and we think of an arrow as a thing which takes `b`s, does something and gives `c`s. So this means `app` is an arrow that takes an arrow and a value, and can produce the value that the first arrow would have produced on that input.

   It doesn't have `->` in the type signature because when programming with arrows, we can turn any function into an arrow using `arr :: Arrow (~>) => (b -> c) -> b ~> c`, but you can't turn every arrow into a function, thus `(b ~> c, b) ~> c` is usable where `(b ~> c, b) -> c` or `(b -> c, b) ~> c` would not be.

   We can easily make an arrow that produces an arrow or even multiple arrows, even without ArrowApply, just by doing `produceArrow :: Arrow (~>) => (b ~> c) -> (any ~> (b ~> c))` defined with `produceArrow a = arr (const a)`. The difficulty is in making that arrow do any arrow work - how to you get an arrow that you produced to be the next arrow? You can't pop it in as the next computation using `>>>` like you can do with a monadic **function** `Monad m => a -> m b` (just do `id :: m a -> m a`!), because, crucially, arrows aren't functions, but using `app`, we can make the next arrow do whatever the arrow produced by the previous arrow would have done.

   Thus ArrowApply gives you the runtime-generated computation runnability that you have from Monad.
4. **Why would we ever want to use applicative arrows over monads?**
    Er, do you mean Arrows or Applicative Functors? Applicative Functors are great. They're more general than either Monad or Arrow (see the paper) so have less interface-specified functionality, but are more widely applicable (get it? applicable/applicative chortle chortle lol rofl category theory humor hahahaha).

   Applicative Functors have a lovely syntax that looks very like pure function application. `f <$> ma <*> mb <*> mc` runs `ma` then `mb` then `mc` and applies the pure function `f` to the three results. For example. `(+) <$> readLn <*> readLn` reads two integers from the user and adds them.

   You can use Applicative to get the generality, and you can use Monads to get the interface-functionality, so you could argue that theoretically we don't need them, but some people like the notation for arrows because it's like do notation, and you can indeed use `Arrow` to implement parsers that have a static component, thus apply compile-time optimisations. I believe you can do that with Applicative, but it was done with Arrow first.

   **A note about Applicative being "less powerful":**
    The paper points out that `Applicative` is more general than `Monad`, but you *could* make Applicative functors have the same abilities by providing a function `run :: Applicative f => f (f b) -> f b` that lets you run a produced computation, or `use :: Applicative f => f (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b` that allows you to promote a produced computation to a computation. If we define `join = run` and `unit = (<$>)` we get the two functions that make one theoretical basis for Monads, and if we define `(>>=) = flip (use.pure)` and `return = unit` we get the other one that's used in Haskell. There isn't an `ApplicativeRun` class, simply because if you can make that, you can make a monad, and the type signatures are almost identical. The only reason we have `ArrowApply` instead of reusing `Monad` is that the types aren't identical; `~>` is abstracted (generalised) into the interface in ArrowApply but function application `->` is used directly in Monad. This distinction is what makes programming with Arrows feel different in many ways to programming in monads, despite the equivalence of ArrowApply and Monad.
5. < cough > **Why would we ever want to use Arrows/ArrowApply over Monad?**
    OK, I admit I knew that's what you meant, but wanted to talk about Applicative functors and got so carried away I forgot to answer!

   Capability reasons: Yes, you would want to use Arrow over Monad if you had something that can't be made into a monad. The motivating example that brought us Arrows in the first place was parsers - you can use Arrow to write a parser library that does static analysis in the combinators, thus making more efficient parsers. The previous Monadic parsers can't do this because they represent a parser as a function, which can do arbitrary things to the input without recording them statically, so you can't analyse them at compile time/combine time.

   Syntactic reasons: No, I personally wouldn't want to use Arrow based parsers, because I dislike the arrow `proc`/`do` notation - I find it even worse than the monadic notation. My preferred notation for parsers is Applicative, and you might be able to write an Applicative parser library that does the efficient static analysis that the Arrow one does, although I freely admit that the parser libraries I commonly use don't, *possibly* because they want to supply a Monadic interface.

   - Monad:

     ```
         parseTerm = do
              x <- parseSubterm
              o <- parseOperator
              y <- parseSubterm
              return $ Term x o y
     ```
   - Arrow:

     ```
         parseTerm = proc _ -> do
              x <- parseSubterm -< ()
              o <- parseOperator -< ()
              y <- parseSubterm -< ()
              returnA -< Term x o y
     ```
   - Applicative:

     ```
         parseTerm = Term <$> parseSubterm <*> parseOperator <*> parseSubterm
     ```

     That just looks like function application using `$` a few times. Mmmmm. Neat. Clear. Low syntax. Reminds me why I prefer Haskell to any imperative programming language.

## Why does app in ArrowApply make a Monad?

There's a Monad instance in the ArrowApply section of the [Control.Arrow](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Control-Arrow.html#ArrowMonad) module, and I'll edit in `(~>)` instead of `a` for my clarity of thought. (I've left `Functor` in because it's silly to define Monad without Functor anyway - you should define `fmap f xs  =  xs >>= return . f`.):

```
newtype ArrowMonad (~>) b = ArrowMonad (() ~> b)

instance Arrow (~>) => Functor (ArrowMonad (~>)) where
    fmap f (ArrowMonad m) = ArrowMonad $ m >>> arr f

instance ArrowApply (~>) => Monad (ArrowMonad (~>)) where
    return x = ArrowMonad (arr (\_ -> x))
    ArrowMonad m >>= f = ArrowMonad $
        m >>> arr (\x -> let ArrowMonad h = f x in (h, ())) >>> app
```

What does that do? Well, first, `ArrowMonad` is a `newtype` instead of a type synonym just so we can make the instance without all sorts of nasty type system problems, but lets ignore that to go for conceptual clarity over compilability by substituting in as if it were `type ArrowMonad (~>) b = () ~> b`

```
instance Arrow (~>) => Functor (() ~>) where
    fmap f m = m >>> arr f
```

(using an uncompilable type operator section `(()~>)` as a type constructor)

```
instance ArrowApply (~>) => Monad (() ~>) where
 -- return :: b -> (() ~> b)
    return x = arr (\_ -> x)
 -- (>>=) ::   ()~>a   ->    (a  ->  ()~>b )   ->   ()~>b 
    m >>= f = 
        m >>> arr (\x ->  (f x, ()) ) >>> app
```

OK, that's a bit clearer what's going on. Notice first that the correspondence between arrows and monads is between `Monad m => b -> m c` and `Arrow (~>) => b ~> c`, but the monad class doesn't involve the `b` in the declaration. That's why we need to supply the dummy value `()`  in `() ~> b` to get things started on zero input and replicate something of type `m b`.

- The equivalent of `fmap` where you apply a function to your ouput, is just produce the output, then run the function in arrow form: `fmap f m = m >>> arr f`
- The equivalent of return (which just produces the specified value `x`) is just to run the function `const x` in arrow form, hence `return x = arr (\_ -> x)`.
- The equivalent of bind `>>=`, which runs a computation then uses the output as the input to a function `f` which can then calculate the next computation to run is: First `m >>>` run the first computation `m`, then `arr (\x ->  (f x, ....` with the output, apply the function `f` , then use that arrow as the input to `app` which behaves as if it were the outputted arrow acting on the supplied input `()` as usual. Neat!

Comment: "Why would we ever want to use applicative arrows over monads" -> he propably meant `ArrowApply`

Comment: @MikeHartl I'm sure he meant ArrowApply, yes, but it allowed me to make a point or two about Applicative that I wanted to anyway, with a good excuse for not explaining that bit in detail. In my excitement, I forgot to answer that question! I've added it in now.

Comment: I took a look at the haskell.org Arrow code, and the signature for >>> is m b c -> ma b -> m a c (It seems to be imported from the Category module). But I think I'm starting to understand. Does >>> let you do sequencing without the ability to vary on the result of the previous segment? I don't understand how the library type signature relates to yours

Comment: I suppose one reason why I'm having trouble with app, is it seems like data instead of a function. I.e. like how we can write a::

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi Think of `m` as `arrowFromTo`. The first instance for Arrows is where `m` is `(->)`. If you re-read my answer to question 3, you'll see I substituted `(~>)` for `m`, so I could use it infix. (Notice the difference between `->` and `~>`. `->` is function application whereas `~>` is some `arrowFromTo`.) Remember Arrows do stuff; `m b c` is used very like `b -> m c` from Monads is, which is why I call `m` `~>`, and write `b ~> c` instead of `(~>) b c`. (So `>>>` in Arrows works very much like `>=>` from Control.Monad.)

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi Yes, `>>>` does let you do sequencing without the ability to vary on the result of the previous argument, just like `>=>` does for Monads. `>=>` has type signature `Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (c -> m d) -> (b -> m d)` which could be written `Monad m => ((->) b (m c)) -> ((->) c (m d)) -> ((->) b (m d)`. Compare that with `Arrow (~>) => ((~>) b c) -> ((~>) c d) -> ((~>) b d)`, or equivalently, `Arrow (~>) => (b ~> c) -> (c ~> d) -> (b ~> d)`

Comment: What I'm saying is that `Monad m => b -> m c` is like `Arrow (~>) => b ~> c` in arrows, or equivalently, `Monad m => (->) b (m c)` is like `Arrow (~>) => (~>) b c` which is _the same_ as `Arrow a => a b c`. In Monads you allow the return type `m c` to vary in complex ways, in Arrows you allow the whole function-like operation's type signature to vary in complex ways.

Comment: You say `(>>=) = flip use` but `use :: Applicative f => f (a -> f b) -> f a -> f b` -- seems to me the first argument of `use` has an extra `f` versus the second argument of `(>>=)`.

Comment: @BenMillwood Oh yes - forgot to `pure` it first. Fixed now. Ta.

Comment: Why should `ArrowApply` and `Monad` be equivalent? Obviously, given one of them, we can define an instance of the other, but are the maps inverses of each other? Take an `ArrowApply (~>)`, define its `Monad m`, why should `a -> m b` be equivalent to `a ~> b`? Take for example `a ~> b := a -> (b, a ~> b)`, which is a stateful stream processor, then `m b = () -> (b, m b)`, so `a -> m b = a -> (b, m b) = a -> (b, () ~> b)`, which is not at all equivalent to `a ~> b = a -> (b, a ~> b)`.

Answer (score 10):

Viewpoint A is a bit odd--generally speaking, an abstraction is not going to be both more powerful and more general than some other abstraction; the two are at odds. Having "more power" means knowing *more* about the structure of what you're working with, which means more restrictions. At one extreme, you know exactly which type you're working with. This is extremely powerful; you can apply any valid function to it. On the other hand, it is also not general in the least: code written with this assumption only applies to that type! At the other extreme, you can know *nothing* about your type (e.g. having a type variable `a`). This is very general, applying to *every* type, but also not powerful at all, since you don't have enough information to do anything at all!

An example more rooted in real code is the difference between `Functor` and `Applicative`. Here, `Functor` is more general--strictly more types are `Functor`s than `Applicative`s, since every `Applicative` is also a `Functor` but no vice versa. However, since `Applicative` carries more structure, it's strictly more powerful. With `Functor`, you can only map single-argument functions over your type; with `Applicative`, you can map functions of any number of arguments. Again: one is more general, the other more powerful.

So which is it? Are arrows more powerful or more general than monads? This is a harder question than comparing functors, applicative functors and monads because arrows are a very different beast. They even have a different kind: monads et al have kind `* -> *` where arrows have kind `* -> * -> *`. Happily, it turns out that we can identify arrows with applicative functors/monads, so we can actually answer this question meaningfully: arrows are more general than monads and, consequently, less powerful. Given any monad, we can construct an arrow out of it, but we can't construct a monad for every arrow.

The basic idea is as follows:

```
instance Monad m => Category (a -> m b) where
  id = return
  (f . g) x = g x >>= f

instance Monad m => Arrow (a -> m b) where
  arr f = return . f
  first f (x, y) = f x >>= \ x' -> return (x', y)
```

However, since we have an arrow instance for `a -> b`, we have to wrap `a -> m b` into a `newtype` in real code. This `newtype` is called `Klesli` (because of [Klesli categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category)).

However, we can't go the other way--there is no construction to get a `Monad` out of *any* `Arrow`. This happens because an `Arrow` computation can't change its structure based on the values flowing through it while monads can. The only way around this is to add power to your arrow abstraction with some additional primitive function; this is exactly what `ArrowApply` does.

The `>>>` operator for arrows is a generalization of `.` for functions, and so has the same general restrictions. `>>=`, on the other hand, is more like a generalization of function *application*. Note the types: for `>>>`, both sides are arrows; for `>>=`, the first argument is a value (`m a`) and the second a function. Moreover, the result of `>>>` is another arrow where the result of `>>=` is a value. Since arrows only have `>>>` but no notion equivalent to `>>=`, you can't "apply" them to arguments in general--you can only construct arrow pipelines. The actual apply/run function would have to be specific to any given arrow. Monads, on the other hand, are defined in terms of `>>=` and so come with some notion of application by default.

`ArrowApply` just extends arrows with `app`, which is a general notion of application. Let's imagine normal function application:

```
apply :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
apply f x = f x
```

we can uncurry this to get:

```
apply :: ((b -> c), b) -> c
```

The way arrows generalize functions is basically by replacing `->` with a variable (`a`). Let's do this for `apply` by replacing both occurrences of `->` with an infix `a`:

```
apply :: (b `a` c, b) `a` c
```

We can still see the same structure as the first version of `apply`, just uncurried and with `` `a` `` instead of `->`. Now if we just get rid of the backticks and make `a` prefix, we get the signature for `app`:

```
app :: a (a b c, b) c
```

So we see how `ArrowApply` just adds some notion of application to arrows. This is a prallel to `>>=`, which is a notion of application for monads (or, in particular, functions of the shape `a -> m b`). This is enough additional structure to build a monad from an arrow, so `ArrowApply` is isomorphic to `Monad`.

Why would we ever want to use these? Honestly, I don't think we would. Arrows are pretty overrated, so stick to monads and applicative functors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm starting to understand how `~>` sort of generalizes `->`. But in terms of basic Haskell, I can't wrap my head around what app is. It has no `->` so you can't apply it to anything right? as in, `app x` shouldn't be a valid expression, any more than `"foo" (5::Int)` is. I know that's not how you use app, but it's none the less confusing.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi You're right that `app` isn't a function at all; it's an arrow, and you use it with `>>> app` because the previous arrow has to output an arrow and some input; `app` handles executing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Monad** is an instrument, which allows us write in imperative style (step by step).

**Arrow** is an instrument, which allows us write in block diagram style.

So, monad for arrows looks like linear block diagram.

http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/talks/fop.pdf

http://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html