# Breaking out of monad sequence

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to break out of a monad sequence?

For instance, if I want to break out of a sequence earlier based on some condition calculated in the middle of the sequence. Say, in a 'do' notation I bind a value and based on the value I want to either finish the sequence or stop it. Is there something like  a 'pass' function?

Thanks.

Comment: You could raise an exception. Check out Control.Exception.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "monadic sequence" here? Do you mean a manually written `do` block, or perhaps some action that's looped with e.g. a `mapM_`?

Comment: @Michael Litchard That's exactly what I was thinking. If I stick something like error "I am out of here ..." in the middle of a sequence then it gives me the behavior I want.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, say in a 'do' block I want to exit earlier. Like the effect of putting error function in the middle.

Comment: sweet! I wasn't sure what you wanted, but an exception seemed likely.

Comment: @AndrewC No problem, I'll fix it up in a sec. I just did not consider my edit as an answer - just something you guys can comment on. ))

Comment: A nice way of breaking out of a sequence or loop using ErrorT/EitherT is explained here: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Directly using `if`

You could do this directly as [Ingo beautifully encapsulated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17678001/1598537), or equivalently for example

```
    breakOut :: a -> m (Either MyErrorType MyGoodResultType)
    breakOut x = do
        y <- dosomethingWith x
        z <- doSomethingElseWith x y
        if isNoGood z then return (Left (someerror z)) else do
            w <- process z
            v <- munge x y z
            u <- fiddleWith w v
            return (Right (greatResultsFrom u z))
```

This is good for simply doing something different based on what values you have.

### Using Exceptions in the IO monad

You could use [Control.Exception](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html) as [Michael Litchard correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677910/breaking-out-of-monad-sequence#comment25752409_17677910). It has tons of error-handling, control-flow altering stuff in it, and is worth reading if you want to do something complex with this.

This is great if your error production could happen anywhere and your code is complex. You can handle the errors at the top level, or at any level you like. It's very flexible and doesn't mess with your return types. It only works in the IO monad.

```
import Control.Exception
```

Really I should roll my own custom type, but I can't be bothered deriving Typable etc, so I'll hack it with the standard `error` function and a few strings. I feel quite guilty about that.

```
handleError :: ErrorCall -> IO Int
handleError (ErrorCall msg) = case msg of
   "TooBig" -> putStrLn "Error: argument was too big" >> return 10000
   "TooSmall" -> putStrLn "Error: argument was too big" >> return 1
   "Negative" -> putStrLn "Error: argument was too big" >> return (-1)
   "Weird" -> putStrLn "Error: erm, dunno what happened there, sorry." >> return 0
```

The error handler needs an explicit type to be used in `catch`. I've `flip`ped the argument to make the `do` block come last.

```
exceptOut :: IO Int
exceptOut = flip catch handleError $ do
     x <- readLn
     if (x < 5) then error "TooSmall" else return ()
     y <- readLn
     return (50 + x + y)
```

### Monad transformers etc

These are designed to work with any monad, not just IO. They have the same benefits as IO's exceptions, so are officially great, but you need to learn about monad tranformers. Use them if your monad is not IO, and you have complex requirements like I said for Control.Exception.

First, read [Gabriel Conzalez's Breaking from a loop](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html) for using `EitherT` to do two different things depending on some condition arising, or `MaybeT` for just stopping right there in the event of a problem.

If you don't know anything about Monad Transformers, you can start with [Martin Grabmüller's Monad Transformers Step by Step](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.pdf). It covers `ErrorT`. After that read Breaking from a Loop again!

You might also want to read [Real World Haskell chapter 19, Error handling](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html).

### Call/CC

Continuation Passing Style's `callCC` is remarkably powerful, but perhaps too powerful, and certainly doesn't produce terribly easy-to-follow code. See [this](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/callcc.html) for a fairly positive take, and [this](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html) for a very negative one.

Comment: I am not sure it is beautiful, to be honest. And I usually prefer the explicit style you show there, therefore you got my +1.

Comment: @Ingo :D I liked your combinator style as soon as I saw it, so I upvoted yours!

Comment: Still not sure if the x should better be on the end so that you might say `something >>= pass ifOk (do ...)`

Comment: @Ingo that would be neat, yes.

Comment: @Ingo you _can_ use a do block if you put ` $ \x -> do ...`. Why not undelete? Combinators are nice.

Comment: This code could be made cleaner -especially the return parts- if it used the EitherT monad transformer. At the (potential) cost of having to supply a few lifts here and there.

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete You're very right, but I've been [spending a lot of time writing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17673690/1598537) on SO today, and so I've just put some pointers in.

Answer (score 2):

So what I think you're looking for is the equivalent of `return` in imperative languages, eg

```
def do_something
  foo
  bar
  return baz if quux
  ...
end
```

Now in haskell this is doesn't work because a monadic chain is just one big function application. We have syntax that makes it look prettier but it could be written as

```
bind foo (bind bar (bind baz ...)))
```

and we can't just "stop" applying stuff in the middle. Luckily if you really need it there is an answer from the `Cont` monad. `callCC`. This is short for "call with current continuation" and generalizes the notation of returns. If you know Scheme, than this should be familiar.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

foo = callCC $ \escape -> do
   foo
   bar
   when baz $ quux >>= escape
   ...
```

A runnable example shamelessly stolen from the documentation of Control.Monad.Cont

```
whatsYourName name =
  (`runCont` id) $ do
    response <- callCC $ \exit -> do
      validateName name exit
      return $ "Welcome, " ++ name ++ "!"
    return response

validateName name exit = do
  when (null name) (exit "You forgot to tell me your name!")
```

and of course, there is a `Cont` transformer, `ContT` (which is absolutely mind bending) that will let you layer this on IO or whatever.

*As a sidenote, `callCC` is a plain old function and completely nonmagical, implementing it is a great challenge*

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for an effect of break function in an imperative loop.

Comment: @r.sendecky The same effect can be achieved here via callCC + recursion

Comment: Implementing `callCC` can be done automagically from just the type. :)

Answer (score 1):

So I suppose there is no way of doing it the way I imagined it originally, which is equivalent of a break function in an imperative loop.

But I still get the same effect below based in Ingo's answer, which is pretty easy (silly me)

```
doStuff x = if x > 5
            then do
                 t <- getTingFromOutside
                 doHeavyHalculations t
             else return ()
```

I don't know though how it would work if I need to test 't' in the example above ...
I mean, if I need to test the bound value and make an if decision from there.

Comment: That's fine - you can just do the same again, and add a line `if (t >1000) then return () else doHeavyCalculations t` instead of just `doheavyCalculations`.

Answer (score 0):

You can never break out of a "monad sequence", by definition. Remember that a "monad sequence" is nothing else than **one** function applied to other values/functions. Even if a "monad sequence" gives you the illusion that you could programme imperative, this is not true (in Haskell)!

The only thing you can do is to `return ()`. This solution of the **practical** problem has already been named in here. But remember: it gives you only the illusion of being able to break out of the monad!

Comment: Note: `return` doesn't do anything special like it would in imperative programming, it just turns its input as output.