# Abort ecmascript7 async function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, cancellation, ecmascript-next

Is there a way to cancel a ES7 async function?

In this example, on click, I want to abort async function call before calling new.

```js
async function draw(){
  for(;;){
    drawRandomRectOnCanvas();
    await sleep(100);
  }
}

function sleep(t){
  return new Promise(cb=>setTimeout(cb,t));
}

let asyncCall;

window.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(asyncCall)
    asyncCall.abort(); // this dont works
  clearCanvas();
  asyncCall = draw();
});
```

Comment: yes @spender, of course, thank! (edited)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel an EMCAScript6 (vanilla JavaScript) promise chain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29478751/1048572) and [a few others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cancellation+promise)

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing built in to JavaScript yet, but you could easily roll your own.

MS.Net uses the concept of a cancellation token for the cancelling of Tasks (the .net equivalent of Promises). It works quite nicely, so here's a cut-down version for JavaScript.

Say you made a class that is designed to represent cancellation:

```
function CancellationToken(parentToken){
  if(!(this instanceof CancellationToken)){
    return new CancellationToken(parentToken)
  }
  this.isCancellationRequested = false;
  var cancellationPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.cancel = e => {
      this.isCancellationReqested = true;
      if(e){
        resolve(e);
      }
      else
      {
        var err = new Error("cancelled");
        err.cancelled = true;
        resolve(err);
      }
    };
  });
  this.register = (callback) => {
    cancellationPromise.then(callback);
  }
  this.createDependentToken = () => new CancellationToken(this);
  if(parentToken && parentToken instanceof CancellationToken){
    parentToken.register(this.cancel);
  }
}
```

then you updated your sleep function to be aware of this token:

```
function delayAsync(timeMs, cancellationToken){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeMs);
    if(cancellationToken)
    {
      cancellationToken.register(reject);
    }
  });
}
```

Now you can use the token to cancel the async function that it was passed to:

```
var ct = new CancellationToken();
delayAsync(1000)
    .then(ct.cancel);
delayAsync(2000, ct)
    .then(() => console.log("ok"))
    .catch(e => console.log(e.cancelled ? "cancelled" : "some other err"));
```

http://codepen.io/spender/pen/vNxEBZ

...or do more or less the same thing using async/await style instead:

```
async function Go(cancellationToken)
{
  try{
    await delayAsync(2000, cancellationToken)
    console.log("ok")
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e.cancelled ? "cancelled" : "some other err")
  }
}
var ct = new CancellationToken();
delayAsync(1000).then(ct.cancel);
Go(ct)
```

Comment: Why do I need `self`?

Comment: I'm not sure I would feel safe with a pub/sub pattern. It's open to abuse by me or members of my team. A token could have multiple registrations and any particular registration could do absolutely anything, not necessarily a promise cancellation. Unless I'm in full charge the token's deployment and the code to which it is deployed, I have no idea of the consequences of calling `ct.cancel()`. I'd be a lot more comfortable with a solution that gave me promises each with its own `.cancel()` method. That way, total carnage could still happen but not quite so readily.

Comment: @torazaburo Mainly out of comfort and because I'm a bit wooly on how arrow functions bind.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 On the other side of the coin, this is also where a cancellation token shines. You can pass a single token into an async function that might, in turn call several other async functions. You don't need to keep a register of your "pending" promises in order to decide what to cancel, you just cancel the token once, and the whole chain is shut down...

Comment: @spender, yes indeed. Your solution is one to keep in my back pocket for some future occasion.

Comment: @torazaburo After re-reading about how arrow functions bind to `this`, I've removed `self` from the mix.

Comment: you can't use this with async/await

Comment: @vkurchatkin I don't know how you tested this, but you most definitely can use this with async/await. See the additional code I added to demonstrate this. Can I get that downvote back?

Comment: fine, that would work, but it's not really usable without automatic propagation

Comment: @vkurchatkin : You mean propagation "up" the Promise chain? Why do you think this this is needed?

Comment: @spender, thinking about this some more, with one token shutting down a whole chain, have you considered the interaction between the token's action and any intermediate catches?

Comment: I mean that you need to pass token explicitly to each asynchronous function

Answer (score 3):

Unless your question is purely theoretical, I assume you are using Babel, Typescript or some other transpiler for es6-7 support and probably some polyfill for promises in legacy environments. Though it's hard to say what will become standard in the future, there is a non-standard way to get what you want today:

1. Use Typescript to get es6 features and async/await.
2. Use Bluebird for promises in all environments to get sound promise cancellation support.
3. Use [cancelable-awaiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cancelable-awaiter) which makes Bluebird cancellations play nice with async/await in Typescript.