# NodeJS break a Promise

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Using ES6 Promises, how can I break it in the following scenario?

```
addClient: function(request, response, next) {
    var id = mongo.validateString(request.body.id);

    mongo.Test.findOne({
        id: id
    })
    .then(client => {
        if (client) {
            // want to break here
            response.status(400).send({
                error: 'client already exists'
            });
        } else {
            return auth.hashPassword(mongo.validateString(request.body.secret));
        }
    })
    .then(hashedSecret => {
        // gets executed even if I don't return anything
        return new mongo.Test({
            name: mongo.validateString(request.body.name),
            id: id,
            secret: hashedSecret
        }).save();
    })
    .then(doc => {
        return response.status(201).send({
            client: {
                id: doc._id
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return next(err);
    });
}
```

I haven't found any clear docs stating how to break this.
Instead of having chained `then`s I could have it inside the first `then` but on more complex requests it would be nice to be able to have them chained.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in a clean, canonical way.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478751/how-to-cancel-an-emcascript6-vanilla-javascript-promise-chain) for something similar.  I've done this in the past by either returning `null` through each `then`, which is horrifyingly messy; or throwing when I want to break and testing for that in the `catch` statement, which, again, feels hacky.

Answer (score 0):

```
// gets executed even if I don't return anything
return new mongo.Test({
      name: mongo.validateString(request.body.name),
      id: id,
      secret: hashedSecret
    }).save();
```

This gets executed even if you don't return anything because the default return value of such thing is `undefined`. It is assumed that code resolved with `undefined`

> If this value is not a promise, including undefined, it becomes the fulfillment value of the associated promise

Mozilla docs on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise#resolve())

You can break a `Promise` chain by rejecting it early.

```
addClient: function (request, response, next) {
  var id = mongo.validateString(request.body.id);
  mongo.Test.findOne({
    id: id
  }).then(client => {
    if (client) {
      // reject with a type
      return Promise.reject({
        type: 'CLIENT_EXISTS'
      });
    }
    return auth.hashPassword(mongo.validateString(request.body.secret));
  }).then(hashedSecret => {
    // gets executed even if I don't return anything
    return new mongo.Test({
      name: mongo.validateString(request.body.name),
      id: id,
      secret: hashedSecret
    }).save();
  }).then(doc => {
    return response.status(201).send({
      client: {
        id: doc._id
      }
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    // check type
    if (err.type === 'CLIENT_EXISTS') {
      return response.status(400).send({
        error: 'client already exists'
      });
    }
    return next(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break a promise chain aka not execute the following chained promise links you can inject a unresolved promise into the chain by returning a promise that will never resolve.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('first chain link executed')
    resolve('daniel');
}).then(name => {
    console.log('second chain link executed')
    if (name === 'daniel') {
        return new Promise(() => {
            console.log('unresolved promise executed')
        });
    }
}).then(() => console.log('last chain link executed'))




// VM492:2 first chain link executed
// VM492:5 second chain link executed
// VM492:8 unresolved promise executed
```

Answer (score 0):

I break the chain by returning a new Promise which is **rejected** directly inn the same line with a certain error message or object.

Due to that I get the error in the last catch block and return my response in a single place.

```
betHelper.getPrediction(db, match_id, _userID)
    .then(function (prediction) {
        if (prediction != null) {
            return Promise.reject({error: "You already have a bet for this match", prediction: prediction});
        } else {
            //Prediction does not exist find user and match data
            return Promise.all([userHelper.findUserWithID(_userID, db), betHelper.getMatchData(match_id)]);
        }
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        let user = results[0];
        let game = betHelper.simplifiedMathData(results[1]);
        //Append user prediction
        return new Promise(betHelper.appendPrediction(db, user, game, localteam_score, visitorteam_score));
    })
    .then(function (prediction) {
        response.send(prediction);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        response.send(err);
    });
```