# Can I use React useEffect for an async POST submit request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React Hooks and I need some guidance with the following issue.

I'm submitting a form asynchronously. I do use a Promise that can be canceled for that.

Now, imagine that something happens until the promise resolves and the Component gets unmounted. When the promise resolves I get an error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

Basically I must cancel the Promise if the component gets unmounted. The return function of the `useEffect` would be exactly what I need, but the problem is that I cannot start the Promise request inside `useEffect` function since the request must be performed when the submit button is pressed and not when the component is mounted or updated.

How can the Promise be canceled when the component unmounts?

**Note:** I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve `isMounted` that has been declared an anti-pattern according to [react doc] [react doc]: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

---

**Minimal Code Example:**

```
const AccountDetails = ({ props }) => {

/* functions and variable declarations go here */
const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState({}); //initialize state variables 

const handleSubmit = () => {
  const data = { /* computed data */ }; 
  dataService.get(
    submitUrl,
    data, 
  ).then(
    result => {
     setAccountDetails(result); //here is where the error is thrown when the component is unmounted
    }
  );  
};

return (
  <div>
   <!-- form fields --> 
   <button onClick={handleSubmit} .../>

  </div>
);

};
```

**I've tried the following solution, that oddly enough doesn't work .**

```
 const AccountDetails = ({ props }) => {

    /* functions and variable declarations go here */
    const [accountDetails, setAccountDetails] = useState({}); //initialize state variables 
    let submitAccountDetailsPromise = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
         /*DON'T UNDERSTAND HOW COME submitAccountDetailsPromise == NULL WHEN this code is executed after the submit button was pressed. */
         submitAccountDetailsPromise && submitAccountDetailsPromise.cancel();
        };
    }, []);

    const handleSubmit = () => {
      const data = { /* computed data */ }; 
      submitAccountDetailsPromise  = dataService.get(
        submitUrl,
        data, 
      ).then(
        result => {
         setAccountDetails(result); //here is where the error is thrown when the component is unmounted
        }
      );  
    };

    return (
      <div>
       <!-- form fields --> 
       <button onClick={handleSubmit} .../>

      </div>
    );

    };
```

Comment: Show some code [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457788/cancel-a-promise-when-a-component-is-unmounted-in-reactjs

Comment: @AkhilAravind, thanks for helping out. I've read about that solution, but it seems that using `isMounted` is now an anti-pattern. https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @RaresI, in functional component, `useEffect(()=>{
  return () =>  // promise cancellation call
})`  does this work. ?

Comment: @RaresI  refered this link https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @RaresI: As simple solution you can maintain some local var which will keep status of your component's status. If component gets unmount then you doesnt need to setState() on same component. This can solve your issue.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I've tried that. I mean using `useEffect` just for the return function to know when the component unmounts. I declare a variable `let submitPromise = null;` and on the submit handling function I set the value `submitPromise = dataService.get(/*the code here*/)`. Then I have `useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      submitPromise && submitPromise.cancel();
    };
  });` Strangely enough the `submitPromise == null` when the `useEffect` return function is invoked.

Comment: @Tejas wouldn't that be similar to the 'isMounted' solution? Which is not accepted anymore https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Comment: @RaresI on `return() => ` call the cancel in the parent component, like `return()=> props.cancelPromise()`. this also works right ?

Comment: @RaresI: Thats why I am referring  my comment as simple way its kind of similar but probably reliable. And even its looking same but doesn't have any relation with isMounted().

Comment: @AkhilAravind, please check the sample code I've added recently

Comment: @Tejas, I'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @RaresI, can you try changing `useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
       
         submitAccountDetailsPromise && submitAccountDetailsPromise.cancel();
        };
    }, []);` to `useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
        
         submitAccountDetailsPromise && submitAccountDetailsPromise.cancel();
        };
    }, submitAccountDetailsPromise);

Comment: @AkhilAravind it doesn't work. I've also tried adding the submitAccountDetailsPromise  to the state.

Comment: @RaresI this could solve your issue, the same describes the issue you just got "
https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/
Please update here if it helped.

Comment: @AkhilAravind, that solution seems legitimate, but the problem is I cannot create the promise inside `useEffect`, since I need to start the request when the submit button is clicked not when the component is mounted.

Comment: move the functions to submit function will do the job, right

Comment: @AkhilAravind sure, but I won't know when the component is unmounted without an useEffect in this functional Component