# Javascript Promises-- what happens on page change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I am building a react app and would like to use promises to upload files to my database. When the user navigates away from this page and moves to other pages, if there is a pending promise, does it continue despite the page changes? If I were to store my file objects in a global state, can the promise continue executing despite a page change?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Why does that matter? Whatever you'd want to do with that Promise, you couldn't anyway. I guess, the real question you should be asking is "will my request succeed". The Promise has nothing to do with that.

Comment: The promise is a contract, it has no influence on the process of an action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will continue executing even after page change. If you were to update some state after in the unmounted component it would have thrown an error.

Though as you are using a global state it should not be a problem.

Refer [Cancel a promise when a component is unmounted in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457788/cancel-a-promise-when-a-component-is-unmounted-in-reactjs) for opposite use-case.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457788/cancel-a-promise-when-a-component-is-unmounted-in-reactjs

Comment: This might also interest you https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/654

Comment: That is not documentation. I would not expect anything to be running after unload - so fat no documentation found on this. But here is another discussion https://github.com/w3ctag/promises-guide/issues/44

Comment: I added it for reference not documentation

Comment: I do not believe the promise does anything other than silently fail when the page is reloaded