# Abort a query for pouchdb

Tags: pouchdb

I am using pouchdb in my react application. I have a find query and i want to abort the query if another find query is sent before I get a result to the previous query.(for live querying).

Something like the db.killOp() of MongoDb

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The only PouchDB operations that can be cancelled are a replication or the changes feed.

Comment: Oh ok.. Thank you :(

Comment: You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29479435/13860). It's not really a PouchDB limitation at all--it's a JavaScript limitation.