# How to keep track of latest request asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an AngularJS controller that is making asynchronous calls to a service that returns promises.

```
$myService.getData(ctrl.state)
.then(function(data) {
    updateInterface(data);
});
```

When the promises return, I am updating data in the interface. **However, if I make two calls, and the first call returns after the second call, then the interface will update with the incorrect data, based on stale state.**

I have thought of a few ways of dealing with this problem:

- Keep track of some sort of identifier of the promise, and when a promise returns, only handle it if it matches the latest.
- Keep track of a promise until it returns. If another call is made, cancel the promise. The canceling could be handled by the service.

The getData method makes an ajax call (`$http.get`), so I could could cancel that by calling `resolve()` on the `_httpTimeout` object. However this seems very specific to the logic within the promise.

Are there best practices for handling this async issue? [JsFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/xp9oekvL/10/).

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');

function loadData(query, pause) {
   var data = query;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(data); 
    }, pause);
  });
}

var test = function(query, pause) {
  loadData(query, pause)
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log("got back test data", data);
      testDiv.innerHTML = data;
  });
};

test("first", 1000);
test("second", 0);
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: "then the interface will update with the incorrect data" I don't know angular, but are you sure about this? Seems silly, since the callback is directly chained to the request. That's what promises are for, no?

Comment: @Kevin I have added a jsfiddle in vanilla javascript that illustrates the issue.

Comment: `then` also returns a promise. You can assign this to a local variable and cancel it if a second call takes place if the executing call has not yet completed..

Comment: @georgeawg No it is not async. Please see my jsfiddle I added to the question for a stripped down version of what I am doing. In my angular app the `updateInterface` call just changes the value of a $scope variable that is used by the directive template.

Comment: On how to cancel a promise see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492399/1260204 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/30235261/1260204

Comment: @Igor thanks. I had heard of bluebird but did not want to use an external library. That article also includes a vanilla js solution which is what I will use.

Comment: resolving _httpTimeout seems to be fine in this flow.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to chain the second call from the first:

```
function test(query, pause) {
  return loadData(query, pause)
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log("got back test data", data);
      testDiv.innerHTML = data;
      return data;
  });
}

test("first", 1000)
  .then(function(data) {
    return test("second", 0);
});
```

The `.then` method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues).

Comment: This is an interesting idea. In some cases this would be useful, but in this specific case, I would rather cancel the first promise instead of blocking on it.

Answer (score 0):

> This solution is to avoid the long promise chain which may create
>   problem if the chain becomes long like 15 promises in the chain.

Please check the solution with synchronization queue. With  `syncArray`,  the synchronization queue is implemented. If any asynchronous request is pending then it just put the request in the queue and process based on first come first serve.

> The following line push the item in the queue if it's not process from
>   queue request:

```
if(!isProcessFromQueue) {
    syncArray.push({query:query, pause:pause});
}
```

> If one request is already in progress, then it sleeps for 1 second and
>   call for processing from queue again.

```
if(isRunning) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    test(null, null, true);   
    }, 1000);
    return;
  }
```

> Then, if the queue is empty, it returns:

```
if(syncArray.length < 1) {
    return;
}
```

> Finally, on asynchronous request complete if the queue is not empty,
>   then request to process from queue again and set the `isRunning` to
>   `false` to inform that previous request is completed:

```
  isRunning = false;
  if(syncArray.length > 0) {
   test(null, null, true);
  }
```

> The complete code snippet is given below:

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');

function loadData(query, pause) {
   var data = query;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(data); 
    }, pause);
  });
}
var syncArray = [];
var concatData = "";
var isRunning = false;
var test = function(query, pause, isProcessFromQueue) {
  
  if(!isProcessFromQueue) {
    syncArray.push({query:query, pause:pause});
  }
  
  if(isRunning) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    test(null, null, true);   
    }, 1000);
    return;
  }
  if(syncArray.length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  var popedItem = syncArray.shift();
  isRunning = true;
  loadData(popedItem.query, popedItem.pause)
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log("got back test data", data);
      concatData = concatData + "<br>" + data;
      testDiv.innerHTML = concatData;
      isRunning = false;
      if(syncArray.length > 0) {
       test(null, null, true);
      }
      
  });
};

test("first", 1000, false);
test("second", 0, false);
test("third", 500, false);
test("forth", 0, false);
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

> Finally, the promise can not be cancelled with current `Promise` implementation. The cancel option will be added in later release.
>   To achieve it, you can use third party library `bluebird`. The
>   `Promise.race` can be used for some cases.

The `Promise.race` implementation is given below:

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two'); 
});

Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "two"
  // Both resolve, but p2 is faster
});
```