# How may I prevent Promise from further execution?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

So, I have this code base:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const req = axios.get('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYnIfSxQXlLcfndCeenvH8kvgjKfaW51rQpTSR05fOYH6q8Rlt');


Promise.reject(req).then(null, () => {
    console.log('first error --- fired',);

    return new Error('Error')
});


// req is still fine here despite I have rejected it above 

req
    .then(() => {
        console.log('data --- okay');
    }).catch(() => {
    console.log('error ---  fired',);
})
```

Soo, after querying image I am rejecting req instance and expecting that `req` will be in rejected state, but instead it still in `pending` state and I can access it below my comment.

Why?

How may I reject it completely?

Thanks!

Comment: promises are async. i'm guessing you end up in your `fired` log

Comment: you can't reject a promise from the outside.

Comment: What's the actual goal here? If the goal is to cancel the Axios request, see [their cancellation docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation). If not, what's the point of what you're doing? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) returns a *new promise* and the parameter that you pass to `reject` is considered to be the *reason* why the new promise is rejected. It *does not* mark `req` as a rejected promise.

It looks like you're trying to use some sort of cancellation, which native promises don't support. You might look into the [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/cancellation.html) promise library which does support cancellation, or as @DaveNewton suggests, leverage axios' own [cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56281471/how-may-i-prevent-promise-from-further-execution/56281588#comment99177064_56281471) mechanism. You should also read [Cancel a vanilla ECMAScript 6 Promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29478751/1715579).

Here's a simple solution that could work in your scenario (mostly influenced by [@MichaelYagudaev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492399/1715579) on the linked question):

```js
const cancellable = (other) => {
  let canceled = false;
  const ifCancelled = (res, rej) => val =>
    canceled ? rej(new Error('Canceled')) : res(val);
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    other.then(ifCancelled(resolve, reject), ifCancelled(reject, reject));
  });
  promise.cancel = () => {
    canceled = true;
  };
  return promise;
};

const req = cancellable(fetch('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYnIfSxQXlLcfndCeenvH8kvgjKfaW51rQpTSR05fOYH6q8Rlt'));

req.cancel();

req
  .then(() => {
    console.log('data --- okay');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error ---  fired', err.message);
  });
```