# What's the difference between setTimeout and Async await?

Tags: javascript

I sort of understand what each is doing. setTimeout, "The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds." Async await, returns a promise, and is just a function that can be put in a queue and have the results of the function checked in later.

But both allow me to "delay code", they are both asynchronous functions. So when would you use one rather than the other one?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: await usually wait for a code to complete. settimeout wait for a time instance to complete.

Comment: no, they don't. The first allows you to _schedule code execution_ at some later time. The other lets you _pause_ an async code path (and _only_ and async code path) until a Promise has been resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are completely different.

Using `async`/`await` allows you to consume Promises in a flat manner in your code, without nesting callbacks or hard-to-read `.then` chains. For example:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  await asyncStep1();
  await asyncStep2();
  await asyncStep3();
};
```

where each async step returns a Promise.

`await` only allows you to "delay" code in a block if you already have a Promise to work with (or something that you convert to a Promise).

`setTimeout` is not similar at all to `async`/`await` - `setTimeout` doesn't consume a Promise or have anything to do with Promises at all. `setTimeout` allows you to queue a callback to be called later, after the timeout time has finished.

Unlike `await`, `setTimeout` does not delay code in a block - rather, you pass it a *callback*, and the callback gets called later.

Comment: I see that what they return would be different. So then when would you want to use async await? Would it be when you are like doing something that would take a while and you just don't want to have to wait for that one thing to finish to run the rest of your code? While setTimeout would be you purposely want something to happen later? I'm sorry I'm just learning about these.

Comment: @Oci You would use `async`/`await` when you have an API that returns Promises that you want to consume in a flat manner in your code. You would use `setTimeout` when you want to queue something to happen later.

Answer (score 3):

Cool question.

You're right that they're both asynchronous code.

As a simple answer to the difference. If you are doing something like:

```js
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("/user");
    return await result.json();  
} 

async main1() {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("done", 2000)); 
}

async main2() {
    await fetchUser(); 
    console.log("done"); 
}
```

The setTimeout is always going to take ~2000ms before it logs "done", provided you haven't blocked the thread somewhere else. The `fetchUser` is going to log "done" when the API is complete, that might be 100ms, that might be 10000ms.

But the difference is a bit more involved than that:

It's partly to do with the difference in a callback style of code or a promise style of code.

The callback style is an older of coding, the difference here is a bit more than that.

Let's set aside setTimeout for a moment and talk about two ways you might make a fetch call.

```js
const fetchUserOne = async() => {
  const result = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const json = await result.json();
  return json;

}

const fetchUserTwo = () => {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
    .then(response => response.json())
};


async function main() {
  const result1 = fetchUserOne(); 
  const result2 = fetchUserTwo();
  
  console.log(result1);
  console.log(result2)
  
  const awaitedResult1 = await result1; 
  const awaitedResult2 = await result2; 
  
  console.log(awaitedResult1); 
  console.log(awaitedResult2); 

  
}

main().then(console.log("complete"));
```

Now what I want to highlight here, is that although the second example uses a callback style - *they are both using promises*.

When you run the code (and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the full object), you'll note that the log of `result1` and `result2` are promises.

`Window.setTimeout` on the other hand *does not* use a Promise.

```js
const result = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("done");
}, 2000);

console.log(result);
```

The return value of the `setTimeout` is a number, [which can be used to cancel the timeout.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#return_value)

And that brings us to the main difference:

***Promises are not cancellable, setTimeout is***

[See this Stack Overflow question about cancelling a promise.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478751/cancel-a-vanilla-ecmascript-6-promise-chain)

To show an example of this, let's modify our example above.

```js
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    return await result.json();  
} 


let timeout; 

async function main1() {
    console.log("start main1"); 
    timeout = setTimeout(() => console.log("done timeout"), 2000); 
}

async function main2() {
    console.log("start main2"); 
    await fetchUser(); 
    console.log("done fetchuser"); 
}


main1(); 
main2(); 

clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Above, we can see that we can quite easily abort the timeout call, whereas we can't cancel a promise directly.

This is not to say that you can't cancel that fetch request, [as you can see in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061838/how-do-i-cancel-an-http-fetch-request), but you can't cancel the promise itself.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `setTimeout` is static timer that depends on the given time. On the other hand `async await` is something that is not static. It will wait until it awaited function or promise return any `response` or `error`

Secondly, You can `Timeout` any execution but you cannot await any function.

Here is the Official doc [Async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` allows you to delay execution for an approximate amount of time.

```js
let log = () => console.log('log');

// invokes `log()` after a delay
setTimeout(log, 1000);
```

`async/await` helps you deal with promises without function handlers; it's just syntactic sugar. It doesn't actually delay execution.

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve(5);

let main = async() => {
  // without await
  promise.then(value => console.log(value));
  
  // with await
  console.log(await promise);
};

main();
```

Comment: Follow-up question, So then would be combining an async with a setTimeout kind of be useless?

Comment: @Oci depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Both async await and setTimeout aren't similar eventhough it looks like they are but they aren't.
If you are new to JavaScript then, you can think of setTimeout as a timer, so whatever block of code or function is passed to setTimeout it will execute after a fixed time, it basically delays the execution of code, while on the other hand async await isn't bound to any timer, to understand simply, function or promise that uses async await will wait until the function or promise returns an appropriate response...