# Something more to "monadic application"?

Tags: haskell

Is there a clever name or deeper meaning to this combinator?

```
apm :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
apm f g = f >>= (=<< g)
```

It feels much like the monadic form of `(<*>)` and comes up frequently when working with lambda calculus with effects.

Comment: It's more clearly written as `join . ap` which also seems to hint at what you mentioned.

Comment: Good catch! Though it's actually `join .: ap` with `(.:) = (.).(.)`.

Comment: Ah thank you, missed that

Comment: Since `join` is intuitively "sequence these 2 side effects", this seems to be "create a side affect and sequence it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty much the monadic equivalent of Arrow's

```
app :: ArrowApply (~>) => (b ~> c, b) ~> c
```

which I was [answering about recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673690/1598537).

If `app` were monadic, its type would be transliterated as

```
app' :: Monad m => m (a -> m b, a) -> m b
```

but it's also part of monadic programming to use functions to introduce greater flexibility (indeed, that flexibility omission from `Arrow` is why `app` is needed). Thus a better, but less literal translation of the type would be

```
appm :: Monad m => m (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

which is the type you gave. Conclusion: this is the monadic equivalent of `app`, and it allows you to produce a monadic term and use it. It could quite happily replace `>>=` or `join` in a minimal set of functions to define a monad.

Comment: Fantastic—that was the correspondence I had been thinking of. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With the [original Moggi notation](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/MoggiE/ftp/ic91.pdf) (pg. 3),

```
apm (return h) == h*
```

it holds there that `f >=> g == η ; f* ; g*`, with the [left-to-right Kleisli composition `>=>`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html).

Comment: `(\x -> f x >>= g ) == (\x -> ( return x >>= f ) >>= g ) == (return >>> (>>= f) >>> (>>= g) ) =~= η ; f* ; g*`.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this looks like it might come out more naturally if we introduce [Kleisli arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v%3aKleisli)...

```
a -> m b    ≅  Kleisli m a b
m a -> m b  ≅  Kleisli m (m a) b
```

So basically, we have

```
apm' :: Monad m =>  m (Kleisli m a b)
                 -> Kleisli m (m a) b
```

... which is quite nice IMO, but I'm not sure if this shows any "deeper meaning".