# Does Haskell's "bind" operator ">>=" have a name in mathematics?

Tags: haskell

I know >>= *determines* the Kleisli composition operator >=> (as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHiyzctYqZ0&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_&index=19)), but does it ever arise in mathematics per se.

Comment: Maybe the Kleisli apply operator? :-)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. In category theory, a monad is defined by `return` and `join`, and `>>=` is just a combination of `fmap` and `join` (`m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`). That is, `>>=` isn't "interesting" mathematically, but rather an operational short cut in programming.

Comment: In Moggi's 1991 *Notions of computations and monads* he uses `f*` to what we'd write in Haskell as `(f =<<)`. I don't know whether you'd consider this paper part of mathematics or computer science though (or the latter to be part of the former). [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290047/849891) [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561605/849891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>=`, unlike `join`, doesn't really make sense in a general monad – i.e., in a monad in a category about which you don't know anything further.

Specifically, `>>=` assumes that you have *values* in the category (the `m a` left-hand side), but a general category has no such notion – only arrows are required, the objects (which in Haskell are value-containing types) are opaque. So if anything, you should consider the flipped version

```
(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

which according to Will Ness' comment indeed features in *Notions of computations and monads*.

Where you can have *values* is in a [well-pointed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category), where you can express values by arrows from the terminal object, i.e. in **Hask** that's functions `() -> a`. With that, the operator to consider would be

```
(>>=) :: (() -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> (() -> m b)
```

I doubt this has been considered as such in the mathematical literature.