# Continual signal switching in arrowized FRP

Tags: haskell, frp, yampa

I've been playing around with Arrowized FRP libraries in Haskell (Yampa, in particular), but I can't quite figure out how to do "continual" switching. By that I mean that a signal passes through a signal function (`sf` below) which is itself a signal (as drawn in the upper half of the image).

[image: Continual switching]

Since I don't know ahead of time what the parameters of the switch will be, I can't see how to reduce this to a simpler, binary switch.

How then should one do it, if it's possible at all? I'd prefer Yampa code, but am happy with any Arrowized FRP code. I haven't tried other libraries (e.g. Sodium or Reactive Banana) to know whether I'd have the same confusion in those cases, but I'm curious about them too.

**EDIT**

To make this clearer an more concrete, I've labeled the image; possible types for the labels are:

- **in**: `Either Int (Int -> Int)`
- **1**:  `(Int -> Int) -> (Either Int (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int))`
- **sf** *could* be:

`(Either Int (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)) -> Either Int (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)`

(e.g., `app`). But that's only if the part labeled with a question mark represents an input into `sf`. If it represents a more complex switch, the type would be

`(Either Int (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)) -> (Int -> Int)`

instead.

- **2** and **out** are pretty much irrelevant.

The idea is that I want the circuit to behave *as if* `sf` were `app`, with the signal labeled `f` representing the function that is applied to `in`, and with `in` itself being the source of both the arguments to `f`s, and the `f`s themselves. I want to get a circuit that can process inputs and change it's behavior (the signal functions that constitute it) dynamically based on those inputs.

On the one hand, it seems to me like `sf` can't in fact be `app`, since in this case we don't have an `ArrowApply`; but on the other hand I imagine that same behavior can be achieved with some form of sophisticated switching.

Comment: Before someone knowledgable comes along I'll just suggest the naive approach: does `ArrowLoop` give you what you want?

Comment: I can see how it would if SF were an instance of ArrowApply, but otherwise I don't immediately see how it helps.

Comment: Could you give the type of `sf` (and also what looks like two `Arrow`s combined with `&&&`)?  I think that would help me understand what's going on.

Comment: I edited the question - let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think it's a case of `ArrowLoop`!

You have

```
in :: Arr () A
sf :: Arr (A -> B, A) B
one :: Arr B (A -> B)
two :: Arr B C
```

`sf` is just `arr (uncurry ($))`.

Then you have `sf >>> (one &&& two) :: Arr (A -> B, A) (A -> B, C)` and you can use `loop` (or rather `loop` with `arr swap` judiciously placed) to get an `Arr A C`.

Will that give you what you want?

Comment: Aha! First, thanks for picking better types than I did. Second - I think I see the point here. I somehow didn't think to enclose the loop over the larger circuit (`sf >>> (one &&& two)`). But it looks like you're right. `loop $ arr swap >>> (sf >>> (one &&& two)) >>> arr swap` has the right type, and everything typechecks. I'm almost certain that answers the question perfectly, but give me a few more minutes to be sure.

Comment: Great!  Do come back with more questions if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking to have an arrow that's output by an arrow to be used as an arrow. 
That's what `app` from `ArrowApply` is for.

If you want to use that in some looped construct like your diagram, you might need ArrowLoop, but actually the `do` notation allows you to be fairly flexible with all this stuff anyway.

There's quite a lengthy explanation of `app` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17673690) but I'll copy the main relevant bit:

---

**What does app exactly do? it's type doesn't even have an (->)** It lets you use the output of an arrow as an arrow. Let's look at the type.

```
app :: ArrowApply m => m (m b c, b) c
```

I prefer to use `m` to `a` because `m` feels more like a computation and `a` feels like a value. Some people like to use a type operator (infix type constructor), so you get

```
app :: ArrowApply (~>) => (b ~> c, b) ~> c
```

We think of `b ~> c` as an arrow, and we think of an arrow as a thing which takes `b`s, does something and gives `c`s. So this means `app` is an arrow that takes an arrow and a value, and can produce the value that the first arrow would have produced on that input.

It doesn't have `->` in the type signature because when programming with arrows, we can turn any function into an arrow using `arr :: Arrow (~>) => (b -> c) -> b ~> c`, but you can't turn every arrow into a function, thus `(b ~> c, b) ~> c` is usable where `(b ~> c, b) -> c` or `(b -> c, b) ~> c` would not be.

Comment: SF isn't, and can't really be made into, an instance of ArrowApply.