# Converting Monad notation to Arrow notation

Tags: haskell, monads, arrows

I'm trying to understand arrow notation, in particularly how it works with Monads. With Monads I can define the following:

```
f = (*2)
g = Just 5 >>= (return . f)
```

and `g` is `Just 10`

How do I do the above but using arrow notation?

Answer (score 10):

## Changing your Monad thinking to Arrow thinking

The first step to translating into Arrow is to move from thinking about `m b` on its own to thinking about `a -> m b`.

With a monad, you'd write

```
use x = do
   .....
   ....
doThis = do
   ....
   ...

thing = doThis >>= use
```

whereas an arrow always has an input, so you'd have to do

```
doThis' _ = do
   .....
   ....
```

and then use `(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c` from `Control.Monad` do have

```
thing' = doThis' >=> use
```

`>=>` removes the asymmetry of `>>=`, and is what we would call the Kleisli arrow of the Monad.

### Using `()` for input or "What if my first thing really isn't a function though?"

That's OK, it's just the co-problem to if your monad doesn't produce anything (like putStrLn doesn't), whereupon you just get it to `return ()`.

If your thing doesn't need any data, just make it a function that takes `()` as an argument.

doThis () = do
      ....
      ....

that way everthing has the signature `a -> m b` and you can chain them with `>=>`.

### Arrows have input and output, but no function

Arrows have the signature

```
Arrow a => a b c
```

which is perhaps less clear than the infix

```
Arrow (~>) => b ~> c
```

but you should still be thinking of it as analagous to `b -> m c`.

The main difference is that with `b -> m c` you have your `b` as an argument to a function and can do what you like with it, like `if b == "war" then launchMissiles else return ()` but with an arrow you can't (unless it's an ArrowApply - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17668452/1598537) for why ArrowApply gives you Monad capabilities) - *in general*, an arrow just does what it does and doesn't get to switch operation based on the data, a bit like an Applicative does.

## Converting Monads to Arrows

The problem with `b -> m c` is that there you can't partially apply it in an instance declaration to get the `-> m` bit from the middle, so given that `b -> m c` is called a Kleisli arrow, `Control.Monad` defines `(>>>)` so that after all the wrapping and unwrapping, you get `f >>> g` = `\x -> f x >>= g` - but this is equivalent to `(>>>) = (>=>)`. (In fact, `(.)` is defined for Categories, rather than the forwards composition `>>>`, but I did say equivalent!)

```
newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }

instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
    id = Kleisli return
    (Kleisli f) . (Kleisli g) = Kleisli (\b -> g b >>= f) -- composition of Kleisli arrows

instance Monad m => Arrow (Kleisli m) where
    arr f = Kleisli (return . f)
    first (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (\ ~(b,d) -> f b >>= \c -> return (c,d))
    second (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (\ ~(d,b) -> f b >>= \c -> return (d,c))
```

### Your example, at last

(Try to ignore all the `Kleisli` and `runKleisli` - they're just wrapping and unwrapping monadic values - when you define your own arrow, they're not necessary.)

If we unwrap what that means for the `Maybe`, we get the equivalent of composing

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
g :: b -> Maybe c
f >>> g :: a -> Maybe c  
f >>> g = \a -> case f a of       -- not compilable code!
                Nothing -> Nothing
                Just b -> g b
```

and the Arrow way of applying a (pure) function is with `arr :: Arrow (~>) => (b -> c) -> b ~> c`

I'll fix `(~->)` to mean `Kleisli Maybe` so you can see it in action:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Control.Arrow
type (~->) = Kleisli Maybe

g :: Integer ~-> Integer
g = Kleisli Just >>> arr (*2)
```

giving

```
ghci> runKleisli g 10
Just 20
```

## Like `do` notation, but with input as well as output. (GHC)

GHC implements the equivalent of `do` notation, `proc` notation, which lets you do

```
output <- arrow -< input
```

You're used to `output <- monad` but now there's the `arrow -< input` notation. Just as with Monads, you don't do `<-` on the last line, you don't do that in `proc` notation either.

Let's use the Maybe versions of tail and read from [safe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) to illustrate the notation (and advertise `safe`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import Control.Arrow
import Safe

this = proc inputList -> do
    digits <- Kleisli tailMay -< inputList
    number <- Kleisli readMay -<< digits
    arr (*10) -<< number
```

Notice I've used the `-<<` variant of `-<`, which lets you use output as input by bringing things on the left of `<-` into scope at the right of `-<`.

Clearly `this` is equivalent to `Kleisli tailMay >>> Kleisli readMay >>> arr (*10)`, but it's just (!) to give you the idea.

```
ghci> runKleisli this "H1234"  -- works
Just 1234
ghci> runKleisli this "HH1234"  -- readMay fails
Nothing
ghci> runKleisli this ""     -- tailMay fails
Nothing
ghci> runKleisli this "10"     -- works
Just 0
```

### All that `()`

Like I said, we use `()` if we don't have input, and as we do in Monad, return it if we don't need to output anything.

You'll see `()` in `proc` notation examples too:

```
thing = proc x -> do
     this <- thing1 -< ()
     () <- thing2 -< x
     returnA -< this
```

Answer (score 8):

First we need an arrow with the same semantics as the `Maybe` monad. We could define it from scratch, but the easiest way is to wrap the `Maybe` monad into [`Kleisli`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t%3aKleisli):

```
type MaybeArrow = Kleisli Maybe
```

Then we'll also need a way how to run this monad to extract the result:

```
runMaybeArrow :: MaybeArrow () a -> Maybe a
runMaybeArrow = flip runKleisli ()
```

Also it'll be handy to have a way how to create a constant arrow from a given value (which just ignores its input):

```
val :: (Arrow a) => c -> a b c
val = arr . const
```

And finally, we get:

```
g' = runMaybeArrow (val 5 >>> arr f)
```