# Haskell: arrows on trees, XML, and Hxt: Transform text leaves into subtrees

Tags: xml, haskell, tree, arrows, do-notation

## Background

The [Freeplane](https://www.freeplane.org/wiki/index.php/Home) app seems to have died its decades-long death. I'm extracting my data from it. Freeplane stores data as XML. One of the first steps I'm taking is to homogenize that format.

## Question, and what I wanted to do

My goal is to turn every `XText` item in an `.xml`-formatted file into an `XTag` called "node" with an attribute called "TEXT". I've got it done, but in a manner that seems inelegant.

I wanted to do this:

```hs
do 
  t <- getText
  eelem "node" >>> addAttr "TEXT" t
```

But when I tried, I was informed that there is no monad instance for the [IOSLA arrow](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.18/docs/Control-Arrow-IOStateListArrow.html), hence `do`-notation is not available.

Is something like that possible?

## What I did instead

I dug into the raw, deeply recursive [XmlTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.18/docs/Text-XML-HXT-DOM-TypeDefs.html#t:XmlTree) data type, and ended up with:

```hs
module Ask where

import Control.Category hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Arrow
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs


textToNode :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
textToNode = arr f where
  f :: XmlTree -> XmlTree
  f (NTree (XText s) children) =
    -- `children` is always an empty subtree for Text items
    let attrs = [ NTree
                  (XAttr $ mkName "TEXT")
                  [NTree (XText s) []] ]
    in NTree (XTag (mkName "node") attrs) children
  f x = x

go :: IO [XmlTree]
go =
  runX $
  readDocument [withValidate no] "flat.xml"
  >>> deepest (ifA isText textToNode none)
  >>> putXmlTree "-"
```

To see it in action, make a file called "flat.xml" containing:

```xml
<doc>
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
</doc>
```

When you run `go`, you'll get back the "1" and the "2", but inserted into `XTag`s like this:

```
---XTag "node"
   |   "TEXT"="1"
```

(You'll also get back some whitespace; it's not important.)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose hxt?

Comment: No. Google rankings, I guess. By now I've sunk like half a week into learning it. I've really enjoyed it, and the arrow stuff it motivated me to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrow` doesn't have `do` notation, but it does have something similar, called `proc` notation or Arrow syntax. See, in particular, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809457/converting-monad-notation-to-arrow-notation) on the relation between these two notations. With this, you can write in a similar style to what you wanted to do:

```
textToNode :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
textToNode = proc x -> do
  text <- getText -< x
  node <- eelem "node" -<< text
  tree <- addAttr "TEXT" text -<< node
  returnA -< tree
```

Here, `<-` is analogous to its monadic counterpart, and `-<< val` acts like `-< returnA val` and allows you to chain arrows. Note that you will have to enable a GHC language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
```

Comment: It's everything I could have dreamed of.